# ANULGAR => trying to get a template value generated in an ngFor to be sent by an onlick event

Tags: javascript, angular, binding

I am generating a list of html elements dynamically in my template, I would like to be able to create a "delete button", but at this stage I am simply trying to console.log a unique value to work from there.

Here is the variable I am iterating over to create the values:

```
eventList: { day: number, name: string, description: string }[] = [
  { "day": 0, "name": "Available", "description": "awdwadawdwa" },
  { "day": 1, "name": "Ready", "description": "awdwadawdwa" },
  { "day": 2, "name": "Started", "description": "awdwadawdwa" }
];
```

And here is the iteration in the template:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of eventList"> 
 <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;  margin-top: 2%;">
 <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">{{item.name}}</h5>
    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted"> {{item.day}} </h6>
    <p class="card-text"> {{item.description}}  </p>
    <button style="color: red;"  [(ngModel)]="item.name" (click)="delete(item.name)"> Delete this event </button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The function I pass my values to:

```
delete(id){
  console.log(id)
}
```

I have tried variations on this but none of these are seeming to work. Directly passing it to the function like:

(click)="delete({{item.name}})"

Does not seem to work either.

Thanks.

Comment: `delete` is a reserved keyword, an operator used to remove property from an object, try using some other name for your function?

Comment: @shrys I don't think that is a problem. Of course delete is a function for object prototypes. But that won't cause problem if you have variables and functions with that name.

Answer (score 2):

try `(change)="delete(item.name)"`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need model binding on buttons.

```
<button (click)="delete(item.name)"> Delete this event </button>
```

Demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rjhzxl

Answer (score 0):

Just an error on my part, I was not paying attention to my the actual values from the key names in the object.

Comment: Why would you add model binding on button. I tried the code you provided. It was throwing errors on that part.

Comment: Because it was a long day.